# how to save identical faces only once

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a project on face detection from surveillance cameras.Now I am at the stage of face detection and I can detect faces from each frame.After detecting the face I need store that face to local folder.Now I can save each face in the specified folder.

**Problem**  Now it is saving every faces,but I need to save identical faces only once.That means if saved one face as a jpeg image and when face detection progress again the same face is coming, so this time I don't want to save that particular face.

This is my code:

```
#include <cv.h>   
#include <highgui.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int ct=1;
int ct1=0;
IplImage *frame;
int frames;
void facedetect(IplImage* image);
void saveImage(IplImage *img,char *ex);
IplImage* resizeImage(const IplImage *origImg, int newWidth,int newHeight, bool    keepAspectRatio);
const char* cascade_name="haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
int k=1;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  CvCapture *capture=cvCaptureFromFile("Arnab Goswami on Pepper spary rajagopal        Complete NewsHour Debate (Mobile).3gp");
  int count=1;
  while(1)
  {
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
if(count%30==0)
{   
facedetect(frame);
}
count++;    
 }   
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
  return 0;
 }
void facedetect(IplImage* image)
{
    ct1++;
    cvNamedWindow("output");
int j=0,i,count=0,l=0,strsize;
char numstr[50];
int arr[100],arr1[100];
CvPoint ul,lr,w,h,ul1,lr1;
CvRect *r;
//int i=0;
IplImage* image1;IplImage* tmpsize;IplImage* reimg;
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade=(CvHaarClassifierCascade*) cvLoad(cascade_name);

CvMemStorage* storage=cvCreateMemStorage(0);
const char *extract;
if(!cascade)
{
    cout<<"Coulid not load classifier cascade"<<endl;

}
if(cascade)
{
          CvSeq*faces=cvHaarDetectObjects(image,cascade,storage,1.1,1,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,cvSize(10,10));
             //function used for detecting faces.o/p is list of detected faces.
    for(int i=0;i<(faces ? faces->total : 0);i++)
    {
        string s1="im",re,rename,ex=".jpeg";
        sprintf(numstr, "%d", k);
        re = s1 + numstr;
        rename=re+ex;
        char *extract1=new char[rename.size()+1];
        extract1[rename.size()]=0;
        memcpy(extract1,rename.c_str(),rename.size());
            //Copies the values of rename.size from the location pointed by source                                  //(rename.c_str)directly to the memory block pointed by destination(extract).
        strsize=rename.size();
        r=(CvRect*) cvGetSeqElem(faces,i);//draw rectangle outline around each image.
        ul.x=r->x;
        ul.y=r->y;
        w.x=r->width;
        h.y=r->height;
        lr.x=(r->x + r->width);
        lr.y=(r->y + r->height);
        cvSetImageROI(image,cvRect(ul.x,ul.y,w.x,h.y));
        image1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),image->depth,image->nChannels);
        cvCopy(image, image1, NULL);
        reimg=resizeImage(image1, 40, 40, true);
        saveImage(reimg,extract1);
        cvResetImageROI(image);
        cvRectangle(image,ul,lr,CV_RGB(1,255,0),3,8,0);
        j++,count++;
        k++;
        cout<<"frame"<<ct1<<" "<<"face"<<ct<<":"<<"x: "<<ul.x<<endl;
        cout<<"frame"<<ct1<<" "<<"face"<<ct<<":"<<"y: "<<ul.y<<endl;
        cout<<""<<endl;
        ct++;

        //cvShowImage("output",image);
    }

    //return image;
    //cvNamedWindow("output");//creating a window.
    cvShowImage("output",image);//showing resized image.
    cvWaitKey(0);

}

}
void saveImage(IplImage *img,char *ex)
{
    int i=0;
    char path[255]="/home/athira/Image/OutputImage";
    char *ext[200];
    char buff[1000];
    ext[i]=ex;
    sprintf(buff,"%s/%s",path,ext[i]);//copy ext[i] to buff
    strcat(path,buff);//concat path & buff
    cvSaveImage(buff,img);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: ... openCV only detects faces in general. In default no biometric data to separate your findings and save them distinct for people. (Hint: you could use the data from the openCV tutorial to store some generic informations as distances between eyes to separate your findings http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html )

Comment: Your title and question are inconsistent. Your title states that you want to "save identical images only once" whilst the body of your question seems to say that you want to "save identical faces only once". There is quite a difference between the two.

Comment: you want face recognition, not face detection only. and please - stop using the outdated c-api !

Comment: Actually I mean the same thing in both title and body,that is save identical faces only once,if the same face comes again i don't want to save that.sorry if my writing confuses you..

Answer (score 0):

You are using the haar feature-based cascade classifier for object detection. As far as i know these xml files are only trained to detect the specific objects based on hundreds of evaluated pictures (see [cascade classifier training](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)).

So to compare saved images you will need another "detection" mode, because you have to compare if two faces are identical with respect to the view angle and so on (keyword: biometric data).
The keyword you're looking for is "[face recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html)" i think. Just build up a database based on your detected faces and use them for face recognition after that.

**Edit:**
Another maybe helpful link: www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html

Comment: Actually my current problem is to avoid saving the same image multiple times.I just want save one particular image only once.Can any one help me to overcome from this..

Comment: what you can do is: save the image and do face detection (with casacade) and template matching (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). If you have a match, dont save the according detected face. To handle your problem you have to do some kind of "double detection" anyway. **Edit:** there are many ways. you also can try a compare function (with biometric data) with your whole database for every image you want to save.

Comment: If i do like this then also I need to save the current image somewhere.Then only i can compare the current image with already stored image.So when i am storing the current images same problem will happen (saving same face multiple times). So i need avoid this problem.Otherwise i will have to compare so many images with out any use(that means comparing same images so many times).

Comment: Maybe i got it wrong, what about doing template matching first (with all saved images) and then do the face detection but not for positiv matches from template matching. Besides this for a comparison of two images you dont have to do a full save like saving to image.jpg. Just use images in your code...

Comment: OK,I have my already stored images in the database and I am comparing this with current images.Input is video,from that I am detecting each face and saving it into a folder.Only by doing this I can proceed,all the details are clearly mentioned above.

Comment: Looking at your approach you cant avoid saving identical images twice, I think. I dont like to repeat myself, but here is how would do it: 1. Facedetection for the actual image 2. template matching for each detected face with your database 3. save a face only when you dont have a match. This approach doesnt consider different viewing angles on a face, so it will be not that accurate i think (compareable to the other answer)

Comment: I don't want all these things.I just want to avoid saving the same face more than one time.Please answer to the question.

Comment: @user3228547 brother , were you able to get solution for this.It will be helpful if you share

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to detect faces in one frame, save a thumbnail of this face. Then, in the following frame, you want to detect faces again but only save the thumbnails for those that were not present in the first frame.

This problem is hard, because the faces captured in a video always change from one frame to the next. This is due to noise in the images, to the fact that the persons may be moving, etc. As a consequence, **no two faces are ever identical in a surveillance video**.

Hence, in order to achieve what you asked, you need to determine if the face you are considering has already been observed in previous frames. In its general form, this problem is not obvious one and is still the topic of a lot of research related to biometrics, pedestrian tracking and re-identification, etc. Therefore, you *will* have a hard time to achieve 100% effectiveness in detecting that a given face has already been observed.

However, **if can accept a method that is not 100% effective**, you could try the following approach:

1. Detect faces F<sup>0</sup><sub>i</sub> in frame 0, with associated image position (x<sup>0</sup><sub>i</sub>, y<sup>0</sup><sub>i</sub>), and store the thumbnails
2. Compute sparse optical-flow (e.g. using KLT, see [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk)) on the positions (x<sup>n-1</sup><sub>i</sub>, y<sup>n-1</sup><sub>i</sub>) of the faces in previous frame n-1, in order to estimate their positions (xx<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>, yy<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>) in the current frame n.
3. Detect faces F<sup>0</sup><sub>i</sub> in the current frame n, with associated image position (x<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>, y<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>), and save only the thumbnail of those which are not close to one of the predicted positions (xx<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>, yy<sup>n</sup><sub>i</sub>).
4. Increment n and repeat steps 2-3 using the next frame.

This is a simple algorithm using tracking to determine if a given face was already observed previously. It should be easier to implement than biometrics-based approaches, and also probably more appropriate in the context of video surveillance. However, it is *not* a 100% accurate, **due to the limited effectivity of the optical-flow estimation and of the face detector**.

Comment: @user3228547 I told you that this was a difficult and still open problem... Try to find out why this is "not working" (could be the face detector or the optical-flow) and then try to improve that.